# variables in list comprehension test are seen as not defined in an exec with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

First, note that it is not like other SO questions about variables inside an exec. here it is a problem for a variable used in a list comprehension **TEST** within an exec.

Take this test.py :

```
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
users = ['root','service']
flag = True
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    exec(s)

myfunc()
```

When executing I have this :

```
$ python3 test.py
myglob_var = my global var
list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    myfunc()
  File "test.py", line 15, in myfunc
    exec(s)
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'flag' is not defined
```

both `users` and `flag` are defined inside the exec(). both are used in list comprehension. but only `flag` is seen as undefined because it is used inside a test.

I can workaround that by using `exec(s,globals())` :

```
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
users = ['root','service']
flag = True
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    exec(s, globals())
    print('some_result as global var =',globals().get('some_result'))
    print('some_result as local var =',locals().get('some_result'))

myfunc()
```

when executing I get :

```
$ python3 test.py
myglob_var = my global var
list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
list comprehension with test = ['root', 'service']
some_result as global var = a result
some_result as local var = None
```

Everything is fine except I want the `some_result` to be local and not global.

to do so, I used a recipe from another question on SO :

```
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
users = ['root','service']
flag = True
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    nm = {}
    exec(s, globals(), nm)
    print('Result =',nm.get('some_result'))

myfunc()
```

but the undefined on `flag` appear again :

```
$ python3 test.py
myglob_var = my global var
list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    myfunc()
  File "test.py", line 15, in myfunc
    exec(s, globals(), nm)
  File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 7, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'flag' is not defined
```

EDIT :

I can workaround like this :

```
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
users = ['root','service']
flag = True
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    nm = globals().copy()
    exec(s, nm)
    print('Result =',nm.get('some_result'))

myfunc()
```

I get this :

```
myglob_var = my global var
list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
list comprehension with test = ['root', 'service']
Result = a result
```

It looks fine except that in my real application, variable assignments are before the exec :

```
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    flag = True
    users = ['root','service']
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    nm = globals().copy()
    exec(s, nm, locals())
    print('Result =',nm.get('some_result'))

myfunc()
```

And this time, it triggers again the same problem : `users` is defined but not `flag` inside the exec :

```
$ python3 test.py
myglob_var = my global var
list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    myfunc()
  File "test.py", line 15, in myfunc
    exec(s, nm, locals())
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'flag' is not defined
```

I would like inside the exec : use global variables, pass function local variables, be able to return a result locally AND use a variable in a list comprehension test. I cannot see a solution yet : Do you have an idea ?

Comment: This is an answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647647/2172752 Just call `exec` as `exec(s, globals())`

Comment: Related: [list comprehension in exec with empty locals: NameError](//stackoverflow.com/q/45132645)

Comment: it is working for me!

Comment: @MartenCatcher Yeah, no, don't do that. The OP has already said they don't want these variables to be defined globally. They should be local variables.

Comment: @Aran-Fey yes, ok. I answered to the post with `local namespace` declaration example.

Comment: I edit the question, see the final snippet...

Answer (score 2):

```py
def myfunc():
    s = """
users = ['root','service']
flag = True
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    nm = {}
    exec(s, nm)
    print('Result =', nm.get('some_result'))

myfunc()
```

> list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
>
> list comprehension with test = ['root', 'service']
>
> Result = a result

The `exec` function may be applied just with one `namespace` dictionary. Make `nm` variable your namespace for local variables.

**Update:**

```py
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
users = ['root','service']
flag = True
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""

    nm = {"myglob_var": myglob_var}
    exec(s, nm)
    print('Result =', nm.get("some_result"))

myfunc()
```

Is it suitable to you define the variables that you really need in namespace?

**Update 2:**

```py
    nm = globals().copy()
    nm.update(locals())
    exec(s, nm)
```

How about pass your local variables to the namespace?

Comment: it does not work because it does not pass global vars : in my example : NameError: name 'myglob_var' is not defined

Comment: @Eric sorry, I haven't payed enough attention to your question. I've updated my answer. Is it suitable to you?

Comment: I edited my question : it is more complicated than that : please could have a look ?

Comment: @Eric I've updated my answer with passing vars to the namespace.

Comment: funny, we found the same solution at the same time. Thanks. But it does not explain why when I specify the locals parameter in exec() it causes ONLY variables in list comprehension TEST to be undefined...

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, but I find this really ugly :

```
myglob_var = 'my global var'

def myfunc():
    flag = True
    users = ['root','service']
    s = """
print('myglob_var =',myglob_var)
c_list = [ u for u in users ]
print('list comprehension =',c_list)
c_list_with_test = [ u for u in users if flag ]
print('list comprehension with test =',c_list_with_test)
some_result = 'a result'
"""
    nm = globals().copy()
    nm.update(locals())
    exec(s, nm)
    print('Result =',nm.get('some_result'))


myfunc()
```

It gives:

```
$ python3 test.py
myglob_var = my global var
list comprehension = ['root', 'service']
list comprehension with test = ['root', 'service']
Result = a result
```

it does not explain why when I specify the locals parameter in exec() it causes ONLY variables in list comprehension TEST to be undefined...