# Strange exec scoping rule for list comprehension with a filter condition

Tags: python, eval

It seems like when you execute a block of text using `exec`, the variable you define along the way isn't available in all contexts. I've detected this when using list comprehension with a filter condition. There seems to be a bug with the scope of the filter condition. Tested on Python 3.8, 3.9, and 3.10.

### Example of text that seems always to work:

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [i for i in a]
```

### Example of text that often fails:

```py
a = [1, 2]
b = [i for i in a if i in a]
```

The extra `if i in a` often results in `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

### Examples of exec successes and failures

```py
In [25]: from pathlib import Path

In [26]: Path("execwrap.py").write_text("""
    ...: def execwrap(*args, **kwargs): exec(*args, **kwargs)
    ...: """);

In [27]: import execwrap

In [28]: exec("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]")

In [29]: execwrap.execwrap("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-fe8166128fb2> in <module>
----> 1 execwrap.execwrap("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]")

~\execwrap.py in execwrap(*args, **kwargs)
      1
----> 2 def execwrap(*args, **kwargs): exec(*args, **kwargs)

~\execwrap.py in <module>

~\execwrap.py in <listcomp>(.0)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [30]: execwrap.execwrap("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]", {}, {})
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-06a3e90e79c1> in <module>
----> 1 execwrap.execwrap("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]", {}, {})

~\execwrap.py in execwrap(*args, **kwargs)
      1
----> 2 def execwrap(*args, **kwargs): exec(*args, **kwargs)

<string> in <module>

<string> in <listcomp>(.0)

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [31]: execwrap.execwrap("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]", globals(), {})

In [32]: execwrap.execwrap("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a]")
```

Comment: The class definition thing is interesting. Our use for `exec` is in an application that controls a sort of highly configurable pipeline to deal with specific data aggregation and transformation steps. The data that we deal with is so irregular that we can't provide settings for all deviations. We decided to allow three custom code injection points in the pipeline to handle any cases not covered by our configuration. If not using `exec`, we will still need to build a custom code executor.

Comment: Do you need to use `exec` directly? For example, [dill](https://dill.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) might be useful. Another option might be to have the custom code provided as a module which could be loaded dynamically.

Comment: I did think about dynamic module generation (generating and import with https://pypi.org/project/locate ), but `exec` is closer to what is needed. We keep the pipeline's parameters and consequent values in a SimpleNamespace and allow the user to edit these at chosen points using `exec` (with the locals as the `__dict__` of the namespace). The available params/values and the effect of overwriting them are well documented. This makes it easy to do things like mutate the output of one section of the pipeline, or cache some info at the beginning of the pipeline that is later then used at the end.

Comment: This _feature_ isn't used that often, since it is a last resort. It's usually used when hitting a brick wall, and an intermediate solution before the next version of the app is released.

Comment: Okay, I see where I got most confused, since I used an interactive session, I polluted `globals()` by successfully first running `exec("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]")`. From there on, it seemed like `"a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]"` can sometimes be successfully `exec`ed when providing both globals and locals (whereas it shouldn't). In reality, the globals already have an `a` in scope. This answer explains the class definition scope perfectly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39647647/1490584

Answer (score 1):

### Workaround:

I have since developed [neval](https://pypi.org/project/neval/) as a workaround for class-definition scoping. Neval is an alternative scoping evaluator with some additional features not available through `exec` and `eval`, such as:

- explicit separation of *staging* and *readonly* namespaces
- returning the value of the last statement of your code (no more distinction between *eval*uation and *exec*ution)
- allowing the stacktrace to access the code text (for better error reporting)

### Answer:

It seems like testing the scoping rules in an interactive session added to the confusion. The variables `a` got pushed to `globals()` after the first successful run of `exec("a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]")`. From there on, `"a=[1,2];b=[i for i in a if i in a]"` can successfully be `exec`ed when providing both `globals` and `locals`, in the case of `globals=globals()`. This is contrary to what is expected from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec), as @user2357112 commented,

> the other relevant weird limitation is "If exec gets two separate objects as globals and locals, the code will be executed as if it were embedded in a class definition."

The class-definition-scoping should produce a failure, but since `globals()` sneakily adds an `a` to the scope, the `if i in a` section successfully resolves to that `a`.

This answer perfectly explains class-definition-scope: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39647647/1490584

Here is an example illustrating the scope failures using a class definition:

```
In [1]: class _:
   ...:     a = [1]
   ...:     b = [i for i in a]
   ...:

In [2]: class _:
   ...:     a = [1]
   ...:     b = [i for i in a if a]
   ...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-430a1ef068c1> in <module>
----> 1 class _:
      2     a = [1]
      3     b = [i for i in a if a]
      4

<ipython-input-2-430a1ef068c1> in _()
      1 class _:
      2     a = [1]
----> 3     b = [i for i in a if a]
      4

<ipython-input-2-430a1ef068c1> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 class _:
      2     a = [1]
----> 3     b = [i for i in a if a]
      4

NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```